# Multiple render takes more time to load in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am calling a partial for 2000 times based on some condition in that partial.
Due to that, it takes more time to load page
times as:

```
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   158.8   +8066.0
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   16.0    +8220.0
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   4.7     +8234.0
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   3.6     +8239.0
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   3.4     +8244.0
            ......continues.....
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   3.1     +22353.0
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   3.1     +22357.0
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   3.0     +22361.0
 Rendering: properties/_reccr_partial   3.0     +22364.0
```

In my scenario we can't use :collections, is there any other way for rendering multiple times.

reccr_partial.html.erb content:

```
<div parent>    
<div inner child>
    page data's 
    </div>
    <% .each do |x| %>
     <%= render :partial=> "properties/reccr_partial"  if (some condition )%> 
    <% end %>
</div parent>
```

It renders the partial repeatedly based on the above condition, also the next render occurs inside the previous div..

for loading page takes 30 secs( for rendering 2000 partial itself taking 18 secs).

Is there any alternative way is available?

Comment: I am guessing that this is not all there is to it. You aren't passing the 'x' into the partial. What does the partial code look like? I suspect that the code within it causes this huge delay, not the fact that you are rendering 2000 partials. Also, what is `some condition`? You can obfuscate the names of course, but I don't really think there is a need; variable names are nothing to be secretive about.

Comment: Post real code if you are expecting to get help. Stop posting obfuscated nonsense. We need to see the condition and the actual code that's looping stuff. Also need to know why you cannot use the collection partial rendering option. As far as I can tell you can always use it if you want to and your collection should be pre-filtered instead of checking a condition when rendering.